# Component selection type for fluid-mechanical system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design, hydraulics, tubing

I am creating an enclosure and need to get a water supply through a plastic wall inside to the core device. I imagine this water line will be a flexible tube and will screw on or snap to an adapter on the outside of the enclosure. On the inside of the enclosure there will be another tube feeding the core device.

I am an electrical engineer and don't know where to get started to speak eloquently on this topic. Could someone point me in the right direction to defining the type of fluid-mechanical components that would be involved for this function or at least help me refine my question because I am shooting in the dark.

I imagine the tube feeding the device would look similar to a line of what that feeds a refrigerator.

Comment: look for "bulkhead" or "panel-mount" fittings. There is a great variety and you would need information on flow, pressure, temperature, fluid chemistry, purity needs, and any use case options (e.g. quick-connect with auto shut-off)  to say more . . . Often you select from a product family you're already using elsewhere, to keep things simple.

Comment: Can you give me some commonly used product family examples?

Comment: swagelok, colder PLC, upchurch/IDEX, barbed tube fittings (generic)

Comment: Anyone else recognize this question? Seem to have read it before but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a *pass-thru* for a fluid conduit going through a hole in a wall is called a *bulkhead fitting*. It's basically a tube with fitments on both ends to accept tubing connectors, and large nuts that screw onto the ends of the tube which, when tightened, "capture" the wall on both sides and hold the bulkhead fitting firmly in position.